# Execute a macro when clicking or selecting a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm trying to generate a MsgBox when an user clicks on a cell. The cell currently has a name. I have written the following code but I'm not seeing an alert.

```
Sub Send_Alert()
    If ActiveCell.Name.Name = "Name01" Then
        MsgBox "You have clicked"
    End If
End Sub
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sub isn't being evaluated. Your sub needs to be called in order for the code to run.

You need to call you sub or code from an event. Events are called by system interrupts (i.e. such has a mouse move) or on a more abstract level (i.e. when button clicked or cell changed).

For your purpose, you would probably need to use the SelectionChange event. Keep in mind that this event occurs **a lot** and can slow you system down or even lock up excel completely. The event also gets called if you change the selection in another open workbook. Make doubly sure your code only executes when you need it to. If a slow down is inevitable, try using Application.ScreenUpdating = False ; ... other code ... ; Application.ScreenUpdating = True, to defer screen updates till after all your code has been executed (probably not needed if you are only calling a msgbox).

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Missed adding the event. Thanks